# Regarding the units of a proportionality constant

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, si-units

I got a general query regarding variation of two physical quantities.

If we have two physical quantities say $A$ & $B$ such that $A$ is directly proportional to $B$. There exists a proportionally constant $K$ such that $A = KB$. Now the units of the proportionality constant $K$ will be equal to the units of $\frac{A}{B}$. Now my question is that $K$ will always have the unit equal to units of $\frac{A}{B}$ or it can have some other units too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proportionality constant will always have units of $A/B$, but these units can often be written in more than one way when expressed using derived units. For instance the proportionality constant $k$ in the electric force
\begin{align}
\vec F=k \frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}
\end{align}
can be expressed either in $F\cdot m^{-1}$ (farads per meter) or $N\cdot m^2\cdot C^{-2}$ (Newtons times meter-squared per Coulomb-squared).  These units are the same once you convert farads in terms of SI units.

Answer (score 2):

since apples are never equal to  pears k has always to have the dimension of A/B